# Invoice VAT - Non VAT

Tags: sales-order, invoice, sales, vat

Placed an order with an incorrect VAT number, which then allowed me to submit my order as a Non-Vat customer.

Is there any way to now change that order to a VAT customer and submit a new invoice with the tax amount that there should be?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You will have to fudge the figures in the database unfortunately.  Once the numbers are fixed you can generate a new invoice off these though.